# Laravel 8: How to restrict access of html content by using laravel gates

Tags: php, laravel

I have DB table with following columns id|name|email|role|password|etc. And I want to restrict some content of my view page when the user isn't admin(role type). I have the following code but something went wrong and I'm getting not awaited result.

Code in my AuthServiceProvider

```
Gate::define('restricted-view',function($user){
            
     return $user->role == 'admin';
});
```

Code in my Controller

```
$user = User::where('id','=',session('LoggedUser'))->first();

if(Gate::allows('restricted-view',$user))
{
   return view('app.dashboard',['user'=>$user]);
}else{
   return 1;
}
```

Code In my Blade.php

```
@can('restricted-view',$user)
   <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
    <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
    <span>Charts</span></a>
   </li>
@endcan
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to getting logged in user by

```
auth()->user()
```